# From action to action to _Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a layout page that displays simple messages to the user.

I have a People Controller with an Index action/view that displays a list of people and I have an Edit action/view for a person.

When the user successfully updates and saves a person's details, I want to redirect from the Edit action to the Index page but display a message such as "The person was successfully updated".

I've tried adding things to the ViewBag but it doesn't persist.
I have a ViewModel Base class, but don't know if/how to set the Index's ViewModel from the Edit action.

How can I achieve this where messages are passed from various places to be used in _Layout?

Comment: to redirect to Index, use "return RedirectToAction("Index");" but how do you want the message to display? Is it going to popup, before or after redirect? You can use sessions to pass messages across controllers/actions. also, you should limit your sessions, you can collect messages or info's using dictionary, then save it to a session.

Comment: I want the message to display after the redirect. That is, together with the Index View, but the message comes from the Edit action.

Comment: you can save it in a session, from the index action, check if the session is not null, thats when you can set the message in ViewBag.

Comment: I should also add that a redirect is not the problem and I could achieve it by adding parameters to the URL when redirecting, but I would rather not do this.

Comment: @GiantHornet, how do you mean? How do I get something from the Edit action to be used when the Index action is executed? I've tried using ViewBag in Edit but it is not there after the redirect.

Comment: from Edit action, before the redirect, save the messages in session(like session["msg"] = <your message>), then from Index action, get the message from session(like string msg = (Session["msg"] != null ? (string)Session["msg"]) : ""), or you can assign direct to ViewBag properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TempData` to accomplish this. Values stored in TempData will only persist across one Http request, making it ideal to store these types of messages.

**Edit POST Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EditPersonModel model)
{
    // .. Your code to edit the person ..

    TempData["message"] = "The person has been updated.";
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "People");
}
```

**Your View**

```
@if (TempData["message"] != null)
{
    <p>@TempData["message"]</p> // Displays the message
}
```

You can build an entire notification system that uses TempData and ViewData (controller extensions, etc), but this is the simplest way to do it.